# Prevent operations from being prematurely evaluated during pandas method chaining

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

let's say that I have the following `pandas DataFrame`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(a=[1], b=[None]))
```

and I want to fill the missing values of column `b` with those from column `a`.

I can definitely do

```
df = df.fillna(value={"b": df["a"]})
```

or using `inplace=True`.

Now, if I want to use method chaining. Because I have other methods that change/modify a and b, I don't want the fillna to be evaluated until it is at that point in the method chain.

I managed to use `pipe` with a callback through

```
df = df.pipe(lambda df: df.fillna(value={"b": df["a"]}))
```

This works, but is there a better way to do that? The above is a minimal example, the chain requiring more steps in the real case.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with a callback, and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html).

```
df.assign(b=lambda df: df['b'].fillna(df['a']))

   a  b
0  1  1
```

Which returns a copy of the entire DataFrame, is not evaluated until that point in the method chain, and is more concise than using `pipe`.

Comment: The `assign` is a good idea.  As there are multiple steps in the chain, I should then write it as `df.[...].assign(b=lambda df: df['b'].fillna(df['a']))`. Thanks.

Comment: @FlavienLambert I think I finally understood the point of this question,... the previous steps also change/create a and b and you don't want the fillna to trigger until those are finished. Yes, assign takes a callable too.